# std::vector::insert giving unexpected result

Tags: c++, stl

Input is a 2D matrix of size n and It contains all values from 1 to N, i.e. each value from 1 to N^2 occurs exactly once in the matrix.
I'm trying to save the index value of input(1 to n*n) using a vector pair at a location n in vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n][n];
    vector<pair<int,int> > v(n*n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
             cin>>a[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            v.insert(v.begin()+a[i][j]-1, make_pair(i+1,j+1));
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n*n;i++)
        cout<<v[i].first<<" "<<v[i].second<<endl;

    return 0;
}

input: 3
       1 7 9
       2 4 8
       3 6 5
output:1 1
       2 1
       3 1
       0 0 
       3 3
       2 2
       3 2
       0 0
       0 0
expected output:1 1
                2 1
                3 1
                2 2
                3 3
                3 2
                1 2
                2 3
                1 3
```

Getting unexpected output after the first iteration of inner for loop.

Comment: This is not C++, this is most likely gnu-c++ with the [VLA extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

Comment: A better matrix representation with `std::vector` is probably `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do (which I may not), you shouldn't have to use iterators. Just do a bit of simple math with i, j, and a[i][j].

Comment: A better matrix representation is to use Boost's uBLAS library with its Matrix definition. Otherwise, keep dimensionality of arrays and vectors to 1 like `double my_matrix[W*H];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing `vector<pair<int,int> > v(n*n);` your vector already has n*n entries. When you call `v.insert`, you add another one on the specified position and shift all further vector elements to the right. Now your vector has 2*n*n entries (you can try to print them all - or just print its `size()`).

You should change this line into

```
v[a[i][j]-1] = make_pair(i+1,j+1);
```

Or, as M.M suggested, you can use

```
v.at(a[i][j]-1) = make_pair(i+1,j+1);
```

which throws an out_of_range exception when the argument is out of bounds. This is of course safer solution.

Comment: Suggest using `v.at()` or other validation to avoid writing out of bounds of the vector in case of bad input.